# With instead of while/and

Tags: conjunctions

Can "with" be used instead of "while/and" to join two sentences in the following context?

> A, B, and C perform almost similarly, with C performing slightly better.

instead of

> A, B, and C perform almost similarly while/and C performs slightly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical AFAIK. But using while/and in the construction you are using is strange. Also "almost similarly" is a bit strange on it's own.

First to the "while/and" situation.

Writing

> A,B and C perform similarly while/and C performs slightly better.

Doesn't sound right. In this construction whatever is after the while/and should be new. As an example

> A and B perform similarly while/and C performs slightly better.

Sounds perfectly fine to me. It conveys the information you wanted: they are all close in performance but C is a little better. If you list C in the first sentence you're contradicting yourself and the sentence structure doesn't acknowledge it. A though would work instead of the while/and in that case.

> A,B and C perform similarly though C performs slightly better.

That is ok. "With" works just fine too. You are using similarly so the sentence starting with "with" just qualifies it further.

To the second part "almost similarly" is strange because "similarly" already contains the information that the performance wasn't the same so the almost doesn't really add any new information. Saying "almost the same" would be fine but that's really just a different way to say "similarly"

Answer (score -1):

I didn't like the first suggestion.

You have already mentioned "C" in the beginning, no need to say "C" again.

However, if you definitely want to use "*with*", the following sentence can be more acceptable and understandable.

> A, B, and C perform almost similarly **with the fact that** C performs slightly better.

Comment: -1 I must disagree the modified sentence is neither more acceptable nor more understandable for me. I actually have trouble parsing it correctly and personally think it's ungrammatical.

Comment: In order to say "ungrammatical", you have to show us a grammatical problem in that sentence. What is wrong with English grammar rules?

Comment: As to what is wrong with English grammar rules, I mean where do I start. But with regards to what is wrong with the grammar of that particular sentence I would have to try and check CGEL. I disagree with the fact that to be able to say something is ungrammatical I have to show a grammatical error. I refer you to the definition of grammaticality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality where both versions depend on a speakers innate judgment rather than on being able to show a violation of specific rules. That said once I get home I will get CGEL out.